# Automate list element accessing in python

Tags: python, automation, iteration

I am working on a simple code and I want to **automate the list element accessing process** in python and store them in another variable. Here is my code:

```
>>>names = ['James', 'Tom', 'Mark', 'Tim']
>>>def name_create():
...    number = len(names)
...    for index in range(number):
...        print("name"+str(index))
...
>>>name_create()
>>>name0
   name1
   name2
   name3
```

Now I want to access all names automatically one by one and store them in the above output names. Like when I do `print(name0)`, it'll show me the name stored inside it.

```
Example : >>>name0
          >>>'James'
          >>>name1
          >>>'Tom'
```

How can I do this in python?

Comment: De not do that. **just use the list**

Comment: What is the point of this?

Answer (score 0):

In python you can't create runtime variables, but you can create a dictionary which is a variable containing other variables in key value pairs such as an index and name

**The code:**

```
names = ['James', 'Tom', 'Mark', 'Tim']

my_dict = {names.index(name): name for name in names}
print(my_dict[0])
```

**Output:**

```
James
```

Comment: You should not suggest an advanced construct like list comprehension when talking to a beginner. It's like explaining the area of a square using integrals and calculus

Comment: @AlbertoPirillo That won't be a problem. He solved my problem quite good. Thanks to TERMINATOR

Comment: @AlbertoPirillo it's not a list comprehension is a dictionary comprehension, hence the dictionary

Comment: and according to PEP20 AKA the Zen of python `Flat is better than nested.` and `Beautiful is better than ugly.`, so this is definitely more pythonic

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly, you want to create variables at runtime, but I believe a better practice is to use a data structure: a dictionary will probably fit your needs.

```
names = ['James', 'Tom', 'Mark', 'Tim']
dictionary = {}
number = len(names)
for index in range(number):
    # Add elements to the dictionary
    dictionary["name" + str(index)] = names[index]
```

Then you can access your variables by using name0, name1, ... as keys

```
print(dictionary["name0"])
```

Output

```
>> James
```